# How to implement instant communication between iPad and iPhone through the net?

Tags: iphone, communication, ipad

What is the best way to implement this:

1.iphone/webBrowser user selects some products (a,b,c) to buy

2.the chosen products most appear on the iPad located in the Store. using a UITableView perhaps.

3.The store staff then decide if the products are available in 10, 20 or 30 minutes for pick up.

4.When the store staff chose the time(10,20,30 minutes) it must appear/communicate back to the users web browser or iPhone.

5.buyer comes to the store to pick up the products he buyed!

Im not really good in this kind of communication stuff! I need help! what is the best way to implement this? are there external api/plugin I could use? I already have an ftp server.

I can do all the graphics and User interactions. the only problem for is the communication between the devices?

Thanks for help.

Comment: By the look of the requirements you don't really mean instant but something like near real time -- they are very different questions.

Comment: "Instant" communication? Break the speed of light barrier. Warning: common side effects include time travel and the complete unravelling of the space/time continuum.

Comment: @Rein: Just add a quantum tachyon accelerant. :-)

Comment: More of a question for stackoverflow, imo.

Comment: Doesn't iCloud do most of this?  Granted it is coming soon, but I think Apple would want their own service to be the top dog here.

Comment: When I read this question I thought "iCloud". Or PHP or AJAX.. whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making a transactional webapp as a json/rest rpc service.
This is probably the easiest way to do it. I have done a similar project and it was at most 1 day to get basic functionality.

Have a look at [grails](http://www.grails.org), [play framework](http://www.playframework.org), ruby on rails or similar frameworks to get you started. A simple google search on builing json or rest webservices would be the way to go.

Comment: 1 standard day of 5 hours programming and 3 attending meetings and asking people how their weekend was/will be, or a standard day of 12 hours?

Comment: more like a standard 96 hour day...

Answer (score 0):

You need a web service (Ruby on Rails, PHP, Java) and push notifications (Apple).

Comment: won't give you instant, will be a time delay of (depending on the performance of the servers, network, etc.) milliseconds to minutes.

Comment: APN is nearly instant.

Comment: near instant isn't instant :) He's asking about instant, which is impossible.

Comment: If you read his requirements you'll see that he does need instant.

Comment: or rather he says he needs instantaneous communications, no doubt without realising the implications.

Answer (score 0):

[Socket.io](http://www.socket.io).
You can use it with multiple languages (PHP, Ruby, Node.js, etc.) and it is pretty simple to get working.

**EDIT**
Or if you don't want to specifically develop for Socket.IO, a very nice startup called [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) can help you do this.